# Tracking the status of vbr from vsql in vertica

Tags: vertica

Is there any way I can track the status of Vertica replication process done using vbr using vsql? It's required because only one instance of vbr can be run at a time.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, because most of work do **rsync** and DBMS almost not involved(vsql connects to DBMS only).